# Chromium OS on an EEPROM

Tags: flash, google-chrome-os, hp-mini, eeprom

I have a HP Mini that runs Splashtop OS as an instant-on OS and Windows 7 as the main OS.  I've updated Splashtop through Windows 7 before, so I know it runs on an EEPROM or some other sort of flash storage. Anyone know how to put Chromium OS on there instead of Splashtop OS?

Comment: I don't think you can.  Motherborads featuring Splashtop seem to put it on a 512MB flash memory.  The Chromium OS builds I see out there need over 1 GB to work.

Answer (score 1):

HP's QuickWeb implementation of SpalshTop does not reside in flash, it uses files that are located on the Windows partition:

EDIT: Middle of page 3 on the HP pdf explains that there is a 2gb partition used in some cases: http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c01951773.pdf

http://phoronix.com/forums/showthread.php?28583-Hacking-HP-QuickWeb-(SplashTop)

EDIT: It's possible to dual-boot Chromium OS and Windows:
http://chromeos.hexxeh.net/wiki/doku.php?id=multiboot